# Android SSL Handshake Error

Tags: android, sslhandshakeexception

1. I have an Apache HTTP Server which is configured using CA signed SSL Certificate.
2. I am using ProxyPass to transfer the traffic from httpserver port 443 to IBM Worklight server http://localhost:9009

The problem is the approach is working perfectly on iOS devices but when it comes to Android devices I am getting ssl handshake problem.

```
(Thread.java:841)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:612)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051):     ... 13 more
04-16 05:30:51.950: E/com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLNativeXHRPlugin(31051): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Comment: Not related to worklight. See here regarding this error what you need to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/6378872#6378872

Comment: Thanks. The solution is to manually add your certificate in trusted stores Android.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Thanks. The solution is to manually add your certificate in trusted stores Android. – Kunwar Adeel Apr 25 at 2:55

Comment: Getting problem in SSL handshaking with enterprise Android devices, Please look into this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51652992/ssl-hand-shaking-getting-failed-on-enterprise-android-but-working-good-with-ordi